# Named patterns and type inference?

Tags: haskell

I was working through some examples and came across an error with my implementation of bind (>>=) for the Error monad:

```
data E a = Success a
         | Error String

instance Monad E where
    return a = Success a
    (Success a) >>= f = f a
    e@(Error s) >>= _ = e
```

```
Error.hs:15:25:
Couldn't match type `a' with `b'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for >>= :: E a -> (a -> E b) -> E b
      at Error.hs:14:5
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for >>= :: E a -> (a -> E b) -> E b
      at Error.hs:14:5
Expected type: E b
  Actual type: E a
In the expression: e
In an equation for `>>=': e@(Error s) >>= _ = e
In the instance declaration for `Monad E'
```

If don't use a named pattern (the `@` syntax), everything works:

```
(Error s) >>= _ = Error s
```

Why aren't these two forms equivalent? What is going on?

Comment: Hint: the type of RHS differs from the type of `e`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's start by looking at the type of `Error`:

```
Error :: String -> E a
```

That means that for any `a` type, you can get an `E a` by using something like `Error "foo"`. However, each specific `Error "foo"` value has to choose a specific `a`, and you can't change it afterwards. So `Error "foo" :: E Int` is not the same as `Error "foo" :: E String`.

So in your specific example, `e` is referring to the actual "original" `Error s` value, of type `E a`, whereas in the alternative formulation you are constructing a *new* `Error s` value, which type inference forces to have type `E b`.